# can not access static php variable inside function

Tags: php

I d like to access the PHP variable static `$linecount` in the function zaehler:

```
if ($zaehler < $linecount)  {
        zaehler ();
```

I was trying global `$linecount` and static `$linecount`, but i get an error message.
Could you help me? I am a beginner.

```
<?php

$file=$textfile;
static $linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
    $line = fgets($handle);
    $linecount++;
}
fclose($handle);
echo $linecount;

function zaehler()
{
    static $zaehler = 0;
    $zaehler++;
    echo $zaehler;
    if ($zaehler < $linecount )  {
        zaehler ();
    }
    $zaehler--;
}
?>
```

Comment: where do you call the function `zaehler()`?  Best would be to pass in `$linecount`: `zaehler($linecount)`

Comment: but to answer your question: you would have to write `global $linecount;` in the beginning of function `zaehler()`. Use of globals is disencouraged though

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your answer.